# What is the difference between named and positional parameters in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, named-parameters, positional-parameter

Dart supports both named optional parameters and positional optional parameters. What are the differences between the two?

Also, how can you tell if an optional parameter was actually specified?

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 528, accepted):

Dart has two types of optional parameters: *named* and *positional*. Before I discuss the differences, let me first discuss the similarities.

Dart's optional parameters are *optional* in that the caller isn't required to specify a value for the parameter when calling the function.

Optional parameters can only be declared after any required parameters.

Optional parameters can have a default value, which is used when a caller does not specify a value.

**Positional optional parameters**

A parameter wrapped by `[ ]` is a positional optional parameter. Here is an example:

```dart
getHttpUrl(String server, String path, [int port=80]) {
  // ...
}
```

In the above code, `port` is optional and has a default value of `80`.

You can call `getHttpUrl` with or without the third parameter.

```dart
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', 8080); // port == 8080
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html');       // port == 80
```

You can specify multiple positional parameters for a function:

```dart
getHttpUrl(String server, String path, [int port=80, int numRetries=3]) {
  // ...
}
```

The optional parameters are *positional* in that you can't omit `port` if you want to specify `numRetries`.

```dart
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html');
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', 8080);
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', 8080, 5);
```

Of course, unless you know what 8080 and 5 are, it's hard to tell what those apparently magic numbers are. You can use *named optional parameters* to create more readable APIs.

**Named optional parameters**

A parameter wrapped by `{ }` is a named optional parameter. Here is an example:

```dart
getHttpUrl(String server, String path, {int port = 80}) {
  // ...
}
```

You can call `getHttpUrl` with or without the third parameter. You **must** use the parameter name when calling the function.

```dart
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', port: 8080); // port == 8080
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html');             // port == 80
```

You can specify multiple named parameters for a function:

```dart
getHttpUrl(String server, String path, {int port = 80, int numRetries = 3}) {
  // ...
}
```

Because named parameters are referenced by name, they can be used in an order different from their declaration.

```dart
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html');
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', port: 8080);
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', port: 8080, numRetries: 5);
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', numRetries: 5, port: 8080);
getHttpUrl('example.com', '/index.html', numRetries: 5);
```

I believe named parameters make for easier-to-understand call sites, especially when there are boolean flags or out-of-context numbers.

**Checking if optional parameter was provided**

Unfortunately, you cannot distinguish between the cases "an optional parameter was not provided" and "an optional parameter was provided with the default value".

**Note:** You may use positional optional parameters **or** named optional parameters, *but not both* in the same function or method. The following is not allowed.

```dart
thisFunctionWontWork(String foo, [String positonal], {String named}) {
  // will not work!
}
```

Comment: ? operator has been deprecated. I've found only scale==null condition in dart tutorial. (expr1 ? expr2 : expr3 still works)

Comment: Loving the multiple named params for a function, this was hard to find! Would look even better in the constructors part of docs? ;)

Comment: Default values should now be specified with `=` instead of `:`, according to https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-positional-parameters.

Comment: Why can't we use both positional optional parameters and named optional parameters.

Comment: Historically, which one was first implemented by Dart Team, "positional" or "named" optional parameters? My conjecture: The first implemented one is positional optional parameters.

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can require named parameters by using the required keyword, e.g.:
{required String name}

Answer (score 64):

In Dart with my understanding, method parameter can be given in two type.

- Required parameter
- Optional parameter (positional, named & default)

**>> Required Parameter**

Required parameter is a well know old style parameter which we all familiar with it

***example***:

```
findVolume(int length, int breath, int height) {
 print('length = $length, breath = $breath, height = $height');
}

findVolume(10,20,30);
```

***output:***

```
length = 10, breath = 20, height = 30
```

**>> Optional Positional Parameter**

parameter will be disclosed with square bracket **[ ]** & square bracketed parameter are optional.

***example:***

```
findVolume(int length, int breath, [int height]) {
 print('length = $length, breath = $breath, height = $height');
}

findVolume(10,20,30);//valid
findVolume(10,20);//also valid
```

***output:***

```
length = 10, breath = 20, height = 30
length = 10, breath = 20, height = null // no value passed so height is null
```

***>> Optional Named Parameter***

- parameter will be disclosed with curly bracket { }
- curly bracketed parameter are optional.
- have to use parameter name to assign a value which separated with colan **:**
- in curly bracketed parameter order does not matter
- these type parameter help us to avoid confusion while passing value for a function which has many parameter.

***example:***

```
findVolume(int length, int breath, {int height}) {
 print('length = $length, breath = $breath, height = $height');
}

findVolume(10,20,height:30);//valid & we can see the parameter name is mentioned here.
findVolume(10,20);//also valid
```

***output:***

```
length = 10, breath = 20, height = 30
length = 10, breath = 20, height = null
```

***>> Optional Default Parameter***

- same like optional named parameter in addition we can assign default value for this parameter.
- which means no value is passed this default value will be taken.

***example:***

```
findVolume(int length, int breath, {int height=10}) {
 print('length = $length, breath = $breath, height = $height');
} 

findVolume(10,20,height:30);//valid
findVolume(10,20);//valid
```

***output:***

```
length = 10, breath = 20, height = 30
length = 10, breath = 20, height = 10 // default value 10 is taken
```

thanks for the clear explanation given from this video link, credits to the video creator.

[video link : OptionalPositionalParameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6eP0jwl1h4&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyHW9voBdNo4gEEIh0SjG-q&index=20)

[video link : OptionalNamedParameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pH-CP8s_xK8&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyHW9voBdNo4gEEIh0SjG-q&index=21)

[video link : OptionalDefaultParameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-Tq70W2cbI&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyHW9voBdNo4gEEIh0SjG-q&index=22)

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Need your suggestion for Null Safety. Thanks.

Comment: That was great simple and precise thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

## Examples from Flutter

### Named arguments

The [`Duration` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/Duration.html) constructor takes named parameters:

```dart
const Duration(
{int days = 0,
int hours = 0,
int minutes = 0,
int seconds = 0,
int milliseconds = 0,
int microseconds = 0}
)
```

### Positional arguments

The [`DateTime` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.html)'s constructor has 1 required positional argument, and 7 optional positional arguments:

```dart
DateTime(
int year,
[int month = 1,
int day = 1,
int hour = 0,
int minute = 0,
int second = 0,
int millisecond = 0,
int microsecond = 0]
)
```

### When to use which?

For **dates/ times**, it doesn't make sense to specify a day if you don't specify a month. If I told you Monday, you wouldn't know which Monday I was talking about. It doesn't make sense if you specify a month but don't specify a year. Dates naturally go from coarse to fine. Of course, in reality you would assume which Monday would be next monday, but programs can't assume this.

For **Duration**, it doesn't matter which you specify. A Duration of time can be 1 second, or 1 millisecond, or 5 days. If I told you wait 5 seconds, I don't need to tell you **0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 5 seconds**.

Answer (score 8):

When the parameter of a function is specified using "paramName : value" syntax, then it is a named parameter. Such parameters can be rendered optional by enclosing them between [ and ] brackets. A rudimentary demonstration of this function can be demonstrated in the following Hello World program:

```
sayHello([String name = ' World!']) {
  print('Hello, ${name}');
}

void main() {
  sayHello('Govind');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Positional Parameters:**

They are same as default parameters. For example:

```
void add(int x, [int y = 3]);
```

Here y has the default value of 3

**Named Parameters:**

These are parameters that can be passed in any order by passing the name of the parameter followed by the passed value. For example:

```
void sum({int num1, int num2});
```

This function is called like this:

```
sum(num1: 12, num2: 24);
```

Also named parameters can also have default values.

Answer (score 6):

From [doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters) we get that both `positional` and `named` parameters are optional, which means they all can be absent.

In my opinion, `named` parameters are more strict than `positional` ones. For example, if you declare such a method:

```
String say({String from, String msg})
```

Above `from` and `msg` are `named` parameters, when you call method `say` you must use `say(from: "xx", msg: "xx")`. The keys cannot be absent.

However if you use positional parameters, you are free.

Comment: The doc says:
> Optional parameters can be either named or positional, but not both.

Where does it say that positional parameters are optional?

Comment: A positional parameter is the default style of parameters in programming languages, called positional because "it's the first parameter, or second, etc". 

`Named` parameters are called like that because you can actually identify them by name and not by position (if you switch the position of two named params, it doesn't matter). See the answer above from Savaranaraja

Answer (score 1):

In the below method:

```
getBMI(float weight, float height, {int age = 80}) {
  // method body
}
```

weight and height are positional parameters, and age is named parameter.

We will call the method like below:

```
getBMI(65, 175, age: 35);
```

As you can see maned parameters make for easier-to-understand call sites.