# What do curly braces wrapping constructor arguments represent?

Tags: dart

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class Person {
  String id;
  String name;
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  // What is this constructor doing?
  Person({this.connectionFactory: _newDBConnection});

}
```

If you precede a constructor's argument with `this`, the corresponding field will be automatically initialized, but why `{...}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between named and optional parameters in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-optional-parameters-in-dart)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This makes the argument a named optional argument.

When you instantiate a `Person` you can

```dart
Person p;
p = new Person(); // default is _newDbConnection
p = new Person(connectionFactory: aConnectionFactoryInstance);
```

- without `{}` the argument would be mandatory
- with `[]` the argument would be an optional positional argument

```dart
// Constructor with positional optional argument
Person([this.connectionFactory = _newDBconnection]);
...
Person p;
p = new Person(); // same as above
p = new Person(aConnectionFactoryInstance); // you don't specify the parameter name
```

Named optional parameters are very convenient for boolean arguments (but of course for other cases too).

```dart
p = new Person(isAlive: true, isAdult: false, hasCar: false);
```

There is a specific order in which these argument types can be used:

1. mandatory (positional) arguments (only positional arguments can be mandatory)
2. optional positional arguments
3. (optional) named arguments (named arguments are always optional)

<strike>Note that positional and named optional arguments use a different delimiter for the default value.
The named requires `:` but the positional requires `=`. The language designers argue that the colon fits better with the Map literal syntax (I would at least have used the same delimiter for both).</strike>

`=` is supported as delimiter since Dart 2 and preferred according to the style guide while `:` is still supporzed.

See also:

- [What is the difference between named and optional parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230)
- [Functions Are Fun, Pt 1 - Dart Tips, Ep 6](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-6.html)
- [Chapter 2. A Tour of the Dart Language - Functions](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#functions)
- [Chapter 2. A Tour of the Dart Language - Constructors](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#constructors)

Comment: You should update this answer. Now, named parameters can and should be specified using `=`, according to the following warning: ["Deprecation note: Old code might use a colon (:) instead of = to set default values of named parameters. The reason is that originally, only : was supported for named parameters. That support is likely to be deprecated, so we recommend that you use = to specify default values."](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-positional-parameters)

Answer (score 25):

Dart functions allow ***positional parameters***, ***named parameters***, and ***optional positional*** and ***named parameters***, or ***a combination of all of them***.

Positional parameters are simply without decoration:

```
void debugger(String message, int lineNum) {
  // ...
}
```

Named parameters means that when you call a function, you attach the argument to a label. This example calls a function with two named parameters:

```
debugger(message: 'A bug!', lineNum: 44);
```

Named parameters are written a bit differently. You wrap any named parameters in curly braces `({ })`. This line defines a function with named parameters:

```
void debugger({String message, int lineNum}) {
```

Named parameters, by default, are optional. But you can annotate them and make them required:

```
Widget build({@required Widget child}) { 
  //... 
}
```

Finally, you can pass positional parameters that are optional, using `[ ]`:

```
int addSomeNums(int x, int y, [int z]) {
  int sum = x + y;
  if (z != null) {
    sum += z;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

You call that function like this:

```
addSomeNums(5, 4) 
addSomeNums(5, 4, 3)
```

You can define default values for parameters with the `=` operator in the function signature, and the function can be simplified as below:

```
addSomeNums(int x, int y, [int z = 5]) => x + y + z;
```

Comment: What is passed into `message` if named (which is always optional) is omitted by the caller? If it's `null` then the type of the string should be `String?`?

Comment: you can declare (not pass) positional parameters with `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

the `this. connectionFactory` in

```
Person({this.connectionFactory: _newDBConnection});
```

is called Automatic Class Member Variable Initialization. See [this example](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2468332&seqNum=4)