# How to pass data in fuctions?

Tags: dart

I need to know how can i pass data in dart like parameter

```
 main() { 
   buildbirdKey(1);
 }  

  buildbirdKey(int soundNumber) { 
   print(soundNumber); 
 }
```

This is example which is working fine. But i need to send int 1 in value or a parameter some thing like this

```
 main() { 
   buildbirdKey(soundNumber: 1);
  }  

 buildbirdKey(int soundNumber) { 
   print(soundNumber); 
  }
```

Its giving error of The named parameter 'soundNumber' isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264231/8745788) and the [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters).

> When defining a function, use {param1, param2, …} to specify named
>   parameters:

```
/// Sets the [bold] and [hidden] flags ...
void enableFlags({bool bold, bool hidden}) {...}
```