# What do these square brackets do in the constructor?

Tags: dart

What do these square brackets do in the constructor?

```
Minesweeper([List<String> _input]){
  //...
}
```

I've checked the [Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)'s official documentation in the sections "classes" and "lists" but neither seem to have a reference to such a syntax. I guess it's a "direct initializer"(?) so the _input field is filled without writing it explicitly in the constructor?

Comment: These are optional positional parameters. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart) and [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[ ] denotes *positional* optional parameters
{ } denotes *named* optional parameters

See - [What is the difference between named and positional parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart)

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. This question is about square brackets. The other question is not. Someone that does not know that the square brackets mean positional optional parameters (many people) would not be able to find or understand the other question.