# Why to use this specific type of constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart, constructor

I am starting to learn dart using their own documentation from here : [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)

I came across this type of contractor :

```
Vector2d.named({required this.x, required this.y});
```

They have not specified what this does or how it works. they only showed this in a small snippet with no clarification. Can someone please elaborate how this contractor works and what is the difference between a normal C-styled constructor and this one?

I tried googling about this style of constructor but couldn't get much because of the special characters in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can head to [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?) and paste the code below to try it.

```
class Vector2d {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Vector2d(this.x, this.y);
  Vector2d.named({required this.x, required this.y});
}

main() {
  var v1 = Vector2d(1, 2);
  var v2 = Vector2d.named(x:3, y:4);
  var v3 = Vector2d.named(y:5, x:6);
}
```

`v1` is created using a "normal" constructor: first parameter will be assigned to `x`, the second to `y`.

`v2` is created using a so called named constructor, where you have to specify which variable will get which value. The order here is irrelevant, see `v3`. Named constructors are also handy when you have to deal with a large number of parameters.

The `required` keyword means it is a required parameter. If you remove the `required` keyword, you will get an error that `x` and `y` can't have a value of null, because you no longer forced to specify `x` and `y`, they can be `null`. To fix this you can make the type `nullable` by adding a `?` after the type:

```
class Vector2d {
  final double? x;
  final double? y;

  Vector2d([this.x, this.y]);
  Vector2d.named({this.x, this.y});
}

main() {
  var v4 = Vector2d(1);
  var v5 = Vector2d.named(x:5);
  var v6 = Vector2d.named(y:6);
}
```

This also makes `x` and `y` **named optional** parameters: you are not forced to initialise them, but keep in mind that you need to check them before using them (because they're null). `v5` and `v6` are created with named constructor, and one of their member is `null`. Try and see what happens when you print out `v5.x` and `v5.y`.

You can also have **positional optional** parameters. Notice the `[]` in the first constructor. `v4` is created with positional optional constructor. This means that you can have zero, one or two positional arguments when you use that constructor. See what happens when you print out `v4.x` and `v4.y`.

And lastly: you can mix these named and positioned optional parameters with required ones:

```
class Mixed {
  final int? x;
  final int? y;
  final int? z;
  
  Mixed.namedOptional(this.x, {required this.y, this.z});
  Mixed.positionalOptional(this.x, [this.y, this.z]);
}
```

**And note that these rules apply to any regular functions, not just constructors!**

I suggest to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgBwnMhz5nE) to understand null and null safety in dart and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840682/2166946) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264231/2166946) other answers related to the topic