# The parameter can't have a value of 'null' because of its type in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

### Dart function

I have the following Dart function and I am now using null safety:

```dart
void calculate({int factor}) {
  // ...
}
```

The analyzer complains that:

> The parameter 'factor' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, and no non-null default value is provided.

### Flutter widget

This is also the case for my `StatelessWidget` in Flutter:

```dart
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo({Key key}): super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, and no non-null default value is provided.

---

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: void calculate({int? factor}) {
  // ...
}                add the question mark to the DataType

Answer (score 235, accepted):

### Why

The reason this happens is because with *null safety enabled*, your **non-nullable** parameter `factor` or `key` **cannot** be `null`.

In the function and the constructor, these values *might* be `null` when the function is called without the named parameter: `calculate()` or `Foo()`. However because the types (`int` and `Key`) are **non-nullable**, this is **invalid** code - they must never be null.

### Solutions

There are essentially three ways of solving this:

#### `required`

This is probably the most common solution to this problem and it indicates that a variable **has to be set**. This means that if we have (notice the `required` keyword):

```dart
void calculate({required int factor}) {
  // ...
}
```

We indicate that the `factor` parameter must always be specified, which solves the problem because only `calculate(factor: 42)` et al. will be valid calls of the function.

#### Default value

Another solution is providing a default value. If our parameter has a default value, we can safely not specify the parameter when calling the function because the default value will be used instead:

```dart
void calculate({int factor = 42}) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, a `calculate()` call will use `42` as the `factor`, which is obviously non-null.

### Nullable parameter

The third solution is something that you really want to consider, i.e. do you want to have a nullable parameter? If so, you will have to null check the parameter when using it in your function.

However, it is the way you would most commonly want to solve the `Key key` issue because you do not always want to provide a key to your widget in Flutter (note the nullable `Key?` type):

```dart
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```

Now, you can safely construct `Foo()` without providing a key.

#### Positional parameters

Note that the same applies to **positional** parameters, i.e. they can be made nullable or non-nullable, however, they cannot be annotated with `required` and cannot have default values as they are *always required* to be passed.

```dart
void foo(int param1) {} // foo(null) is invalid.

void bar(int? param1) {} // bar(null) is valid.
```

Comment: class SectionListTileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext tileContext;
  final IconData tileLeadingIcon;
  final Color tileLeadingIconColor;
  final String tileTitle;
  final Function tileOnTapAction;

  SectionListTileWidget(
      {required this.tileContext,
      required this.tileLeadingIcon,
      required this.tileLeadingIconColor,
      required this.tileTitle,
      required this.tileOnTapAction});

  @override
  _SectionListTileWidgetState createState() => _SectionListTileWidgetState();
}

Comment: how can I make "tileLeadingIconColor" nullable so that if I have no tileLeadingIconColor (null) then I can use Colors.green otherwise want to use user's passed tileLeadingIconColor. Kindly suggest how can i do this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree with you, this is optional choice : use `required int param` or `int? param`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer, but I want to know when the non-nullable feature was allowed in the previous Dart version and in wish one.

Answer (score 25):

It's the main reason why non-nullable feature is added to Dart. Since, you're passing `Key` to super class, which could be `null`, so you want to make sure it's non null. What you can do is either not use the `key` at all or provide a default value to it or make it `required`. Like:

```
MyPage({Key key = const Key("any_key")}) : super(key: key);
```

or make `key` required like this:

```
MyPage({required Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Sorry for jumping in. Compared to the answer above (which told us that it is actually possible to make it 'nullable' other than 'required'), what is actually the specific case that you want this to be not empty rather than it can be empty?

Comment: @DeanDebrio I can't think of a good use case top of my head except when you are you using `AnimatedSwitcher` to switch between two widgets which require a key.

Answer (score 16):

If i get this error from the `constructor` of a class pointing **`key`**,  i add a '**`?`**' mark infront of `Key` like this:

```
const ClassName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

'**`?`**' means that can be `nullable`

Comment: my linter complains about this `?`, how to fix that?

Answer (score 13):

Add requuired function for Eg

```
required Key key,
    required this.id,
    required this.name,  
    required this.code,  
    required this.img,  
    required this.price,
    required this.promotionPrice,
    required this.size,
    required this.color,
```

Comment: but what if I want one variable not to be required

Answer (score 11):

As additional information to the previous *@creativecreatorormaybenot*'s answer, you can also use **positional parameters** (no curly brackets) that are mandatory by default, so not nullable.

```
  void calculate(int factor) {
     // ...
  }
```

and is called without naming the parameter:

```
calculate(12);
```

These kind of parameters can be used on constructors this way:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String myVar;

  const Foo(this.myVar, {Key? key}): super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```

and *"can be followed either by named parameters OR by optional positional parameters (but not both)"*, see doc here: [dart parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters)

Interesting answer on difference between named and positional parameters: [What is the difference between named and positional parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart)

Answer (score 7):

Add a required keyword before the variable in the constructor and also add '?' next to Key.

```dart
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 3):

change sdk version in pubspec

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the SDK version in pubspec.yaml solves the issues:

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since [another user already posted that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903177/2828341). If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).