# Navigator.push with three parameters in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, navigation

i have form with three dropdown buttons and these were declared at top of the class,

```
String _currentItemSelected1 = 'low';
String _currentItemSelected2 = 'low';
String _currentItemSelected3 = 'low';
```

then I have RisedButton with onPressed property with this body:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SuggestionResult(
      _currentItemSelected1,
      _currentItemSelected2,
      _currentItemSelected3,
    ),
  ),
);
```

in SuggestionResult class I was override the constructor as following:

```
final String temp;
final String hum;
final String light;
SuggestionResult({this.temp, this.hum, this.light});
```

Now, the PROBLEM is when I calling SuggestionResult class it says: "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."

Comment: You need to understand the difference between positional and named arguments in dart. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your SuggestionResult page you should **specify** the name of the **parameters**.

```
...
builder: (context) => new SuggestionResult(
    temp: _currentItemSelected1,
    hum: _currentItemSelected2,
    light: _currentItemSelected3,
);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
onPressed: () {
             Navigator.push(
            context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new SuggestionResult(temp:_currentItemSelected1, hum: _currentItemSelected2, light: _currentItemSelected3  
         ),
       ),
     );
  },
```

In Dart we define named parameters by surrounding them with curly ({}) braces:
Like following;

```
SuggestionResult({this.temp, this.hum, this.light});
```

This means that we can create the widget above like this:

```
new SuggestionResult(temp: _currentItemSelected1, hum: _currentItemSelected2, light: _currentItemSelected3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new SuggestionResult(temp: _currentItemSelected1, hum: _currentItemSelected2, light: _currentItemSelected3);
```