# Required keyword not allowed in optional parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using optional parameters in Flutter, when i use named arguments require keyword is allowed however when i use optional parameters its gives an error.

The code below complains that the parameter is non-nullable and either add a require keyword
When i add the require keyword it still complains

```
  TextFormField _textFormBuilder([required String label, required String hint]) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'label',
        hintText: 'hint',
      ),
    );
  }
```

This code below works as expected:

```
  TextFormField _textFormBuilder({required String label, required String hint}) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'label',
        hintText: 'hint',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer, as these are optional parameters they can  not be required like named arguments:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` means that the parameter is optional. If you add word `required`, it has no idea what do you want.

```
 TextFormField _textFormBuilder(String label, String hint)
```

The `{}` means they are named parameters.

Read about parameters here: [What is the difference between named and positional parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks @stacktrace2234
I have just seen your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters in Dart are optional and they are not supposed to be required which makes good-sense.
Unlike named arguments they can be required!