# Stateless widget with required and optional values with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So I am trying to create a custom widget I can use in my flutter app. When creating this widget I want to always select a color (hence the required value) but I want to keep the cardChild and onpres values optional. How do I do this? I tried to give a empty Container and empty function as default values but then I get the errror

> error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
> (non_constant_default_value at [untitled1]
> lib/Components/reusable_card.dart:6)

here is my widget constructor:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {ReusableCard(
{required this.colour, this.cardChild = Container(), this.onPress = () {}});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onPress;
      },
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
          color: colour,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: either assign a `const` default values or allow `null`s - like: `final Widget? cardChild;` - for more info see how `Container` deals with optional [child](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/77d935af4d/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L293)

Comment: Ahh the allowing for Nulls is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use following approach

```
    class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {ReusableCard(
        {required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
    
    final Color colour;
    final Widget? cardChild;
    final Function? onPress;
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if(onPress != null){
            onPress!();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          child: cardChild ?? Container(),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
            color: colour,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: able to resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either by making `cardChild` and `onPress` positional parameter in the constructor.

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  //constructor
  ReusableCard(this.colour,this.cardChild, this.onPress);

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ....
```

or make them nullable by adding `?`:

```
  class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  //constructor
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ....
```

For better understanding about named and positional parameters read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart).