# What does too many positional argument mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart-analyzer

[Dart Analysis Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQXhH.png)

When I wrote this code in Android Studio, that is what came up in my dart analysis toolbar:
[The code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMPTt.png)
How do I prevent this?

Comment: You should start by watching the course

Comment: Try posting code in text form instead of picture form

Comment: Okay I'll take note of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `)` bracket add it before the semicolon .

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart) link explains the about positional and named arguments . And The process you are trying is not a good practice. You need to breakdown the widgets so that it becomes easier to maintain.

Try as follows:

```
    void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('I am rich'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('images/diamond.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `MaterialApp` with this:

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'SaHomeDecor',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am rich'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('images/diamond.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If you are using `AppBar` you have to give `Scaffold.appBar` property like `Scaffold(appBar:AppBar())`.

For the image you have to use `Scaffold.body` property.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bracket in the end before semicolon