# Too many positional arguments: 5 allowed, but 6 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments. Try removing the extra positional arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Building flutter tool...
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies.
../flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart:293:58: Error: Too many positional arguments: 5 allowed, but 6 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
      loadStrategy: FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider(
                                                         ^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dwds-20.0.1/lib/src/loaders/frontend_server_require.dart:34:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider(
```

solve this problem in android studio

Comment: Maybe you can as well include the code that has this line: `loadStrategy: FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider(`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are additional positional arguments in your code. The correct usage for `FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider` is to provide only 5 positional arguments, but your code currently has 6:

Your code:

```dart
FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider(argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, argument6)
```

Instead:

```dart
FrontendServerRequireStrategyProvider(argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5)
```

Also, see the differences between positional and named parameters in Dart: [What is the difference between named and positional parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart)